# Create localizable.strings from Code in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm currently localizing my iOS-Application. This works pretty decent so far.

I've already created localizable.strings and several xib-files and so about 80% of the app is already translated.

But the App also loads data from a WebService which passes me a key, e.g.: "TITEL 1" as well as all supported languages (values) attached to it e.g: "Titel One" "Titel Eins" "Titolo Uno".

And now i would like to store those values in the according localizable.strings files.

For example:

Localizable.strings (English) should then contain:

```
"TITLE 1" = "Title One";
```

Localizable.strings (German) should then contain:

```
"TITLE 1" = "Titel Eins";
```

Localizable.strings (Italian) should then contain:

```
"TITLE 1" = "Titolo Uno";
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to insert them in the localization strings at run time, if the webserver is managed by you, i suggest that you send wich language is the user using, 
Please consider this example

```
//Get the language code
NSString* languageCode = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
//Now send the request to the server with the language you want
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.yourserve.com/yourfunctiom?lang=%@", languageCode];
//Request it
```

Now basing on the language that you receive in your server you will return the appropriate string

Comment: You could also get the appropriate string from the hash using that language code, if you are not in control of the server.

Answer (score 0):

This may be stretching the frameworks a bit, but if you want to use Apple's string loading functions you could try to build an `NSBundle` in your document directory (a bundle is just a directory, after all), fill it with files from the server and then use `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` to get to your strings.

Not sure it is worth it compared to the approach in Omar Abdelhafith's answer, though.